# The compiled class file has been removed

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

i try to add laravel collective form in my project but it show below error please help me to get our from here.

C:\xampp\htdocs\sun>composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.3.0)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader
>   The compiled class file has been removed.

Comment: Try running ```composer dump-autoload``` and run your command again.

Comment: @AshMenhennett thanks for your replay but it's not working

Comment: Other than ```Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate php artisan optimize Generating optimized class loader The compiled class file has been removed.``` being displayed in cmd, what is the problem?

Comment: install laravel form collective and because of network problem stop to install   -- composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0" -- and after that i face this problem every time while i run above command.

Comment: This is no error. It's normal, because laravel is refreshing it's pre-compiled files.

Comment: may be it's warning but its shows error "Class 'form' not found" after installing and make chages into app.php

Comment: Not sure if you're still having this issue, but this just happened to me with a new project and I fixed it by deleting the vendor directory and then running composer install again.

Comment: thanks it work for me..